# Spring security : Redirect to previous url after logout

Tags: spring-security

I've got a web app that uses spring security. I'm wanting to redirect the user back to the same page they were on before log out when they log out.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Are you sure too want this? It the user is visiting some secure page, do you want him to be allowed to on that secure page after logout.

Comment: Mainly I'm wanting them to be sent back to the log in screen. The log in page sends them on to the originally requested page once they've successfully logged in and I want that to be where they logged off from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a new filter in the filter chain of the spring security. That new filter will be applied to the `/logout` URL. When going trough this filter you can save the current page in a field variable. And when returning through the filter. You can redirect the request to the saved URL. I think this can help. You can get the current page URL by using the `Referer` header in the `Request` object.

Answer (score 7):

Not sure which Spring version this question was referring to - but there is a `useReferer` property on the standard `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler` since Spring 3.0.

So all you need to do is configure it like this and the logout will redirect to wherever the user came from:

```
<bean id="logoutSuccessHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler">
    <property name="useReferer" value="true"/>
</bean>

<security:http>
    <security:logout logout-url="/logout" success-handler-ref="logoutSuccessHandler" />
</security:http>
```

Comment: I used this, and it works fine. However when I logout from the secured page it goes to login form... is there any way to go to different URL in this case? (ie. Home page)

Comment: I don't think that's possible with the standard SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler. You can extend it and override the `determineTargetUrl(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)` method to implement custom behavior. But you'd need to know if the Url (as determined by `super.determineTargetUrl(request, response);`) that's being redirected to is protected.. I didn't find a way to do that other than checking the targetUrl String there.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a Simple LogoutSuccessHandler

```
@Component
  public class CustomLogoutSuccessHandler extends 
  SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler implements LogoutSuccessHandler {

@Override
 public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
     response, Authentication authentication)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    if (authentication != null) {
        System.out.println(authentication.getName());
    }
    response.setStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value());
    response.sendRedirect(request.getHeader("referer"));
}
```

And later call it in your configure method i.e

```
.logout().logoutSuccessHandler(customLogoutSuccessHandler)
```

This will redirect you to referer URL.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought:

How about we keep a stack of visited pages. may be at max 3 entries. and redirects user from logout.

- Configure a Filter or extend spring security filter to maintain a stack in session about last two visited URLs
- On logout configure a servlet as `logout-success-url` .
- Now get the URL from session stack and *now* invalidate the session and redirect user to that page

Also you can make use of [referrer header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer) as Vijay has mentioned